# logcat error: can't open file for reading

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, logcat

ALL of my project have this error: "can't open file for reading" in logcat. 
May I know is my eclipse got problem or I need to add some permission in some where?

What should I do to remove this error?

[image]

Comment: what else information is shown in logcat? .. if not a screenshot will be helpful

Comment: i had added the screenshot, nothing else but just the "can't open file for reading" error..
and this error shown in ALL of my other project.

Comment: not sure about that ,, but you can try updating your sdk and adt

Comment: sdk can update via sdk manager right? but how to update adt?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html .. check this